# Redirect list of url at once

Tags: sitecore, http-redirect

I have list of URLs in excel sheet and I need to redirect all those URLs at a single location in site core
Is there any way to redirect all URLs at once or is there any way to redirect multiple sitecore items in a single go

I have tried but I didn't able to find a way to redirect  all URLs at once there is option for single item but it's not feasible because I have list of up to 500 items

Answer (score 0):

You can try 301 Redirect Module (older version) or SXA Redirect feature.
To redirect all the URLs at once or not is depending on will you able to create a regex express to match all the URLs.